# Elegant presentation of NBG?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm looking for an elegant presentation of NBG set theory, specifically where all objects are treated as classes, and sets are defined with something like $Set(x) \equiv \exists y : x \in y$.
The axioms would incorporate this, eg comprehension would be something like
$$\forall Set(S) : \exists A : \forall Set(x) (x \in A \iff x \in S \land \phi(x))$$
I've looked at many presentations, like Jech's Set Theory and Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic, but they all seem to treat sets and classes as fundamentally different objects of the domain. Any recommendations?

Comment: But... ${}{}$Why?

Comment: Distinguishing sets and classes have the benefit that we can 'separate' 'first-order parts' (namely, about sets) from 'second-order parts.' This is important when we work with models of second-order set theories like $\mathsf{NBG}$ or $\mathsf{MK}$, which is sometimes constructed from by adding a collection of classes to a model of first-order set theories like $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: P.Bernays, [Axiomatic Set Theory (1958)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Axiomatic_Set_Theory/iulLAAAAMAAJ) with free set- and class-variables (page 48: $a,b,c$ for sets and $\mathfrak A, \mathfrak B, \mathfrak C$ for classes) and the class-terms schematic rule:  $c \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \} \leftrightarrow \varphi(c)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I want to put it on a site that takes public contributions and can't be relied on to keep a consistent convention. There are also non class things that it would have to be sort of compatible with